# Off topic question on hold, no real answer

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

So I asked [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/226112/105571), which is now on hold. I get why it's on hold (off topic), but I specifically asked in the question if there might be a better stack where the question might be fit for migration. Apparently the community decided there wasn't.

Anyway, while the only existing answer did provide some interesting information, it didn't really answer the question (see the edits for the resolution).

My meta-question is if I should just delete the question, since the community decided it was off topic anyway. Or leave it, since the existing answer is very interesting.

I'd rather delete it myself, rather than incur the negative rep and black marks of having the community delete or close my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I specifically asked in the question if there might be a better stack where the question might be fit for migration.

Not our problem.  Off topic here is off topic here, whether we know of a better place for the question or one exists or not.  We are not the help desk for the SE site or the rest of the internet.

> Apparently the community decided there wasn't.

More likely they didn't want to encourage people coming here dumping random questions on us expecting us to tell them where those questions really should have been asked.

We are here to discuss electrical engineering, not how to use the internet.

> Anyway, while the only existing answer did provide some interesting information, it didn't really answer the question (see the edits for the resolution).

I didn't see the question originally, but what Spehro said was the first thing that went thru my mind as I was reading your symptoms.  It is actually a very reasonable answer to the information you provided.

> My meta-question is if I should just delete the question, since the community decided it was off topic anyway. Or leave it, since the existing answer is very interesting.

Leave it.

> I'd rather delete it myself, rather than incur the negative rep and black marks of having the community delete or close my question.

I'm not sure it works that way.  I believe the algorithm that checks your posting quality and suspends your posting privilege if too low is not fooled by you deleting low quality posts.  In fact, I think that makes things worse.

You probably can't delete it anyway since there is a upvoted answer.  Put another way, you have no right to delete Spehro's answer, which is what deleting the whole question would do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of answer you were expecting without specifying anything about your device (like a make or model... not that it would have made any difference).

I'm fairly sure *you* can't delete the question, but that's the site logic if you have an up-voted answer on your question. The self-deletion prevention is there to protect answer writers that put effort into writing their answers. I'd rather leave it for the same reason.

Comment: ATM I can delete the question, but it warns me against deleting a question with answers... but my meta question still stands, is this question *really* useful to this stack? And I agree, make and model would make no difference to the answer on this stack. Thus my original sub-question: where might that question fit better?

Comment: @CDspace Interesting. There is no place for consumer electronics support/analysis. Even diving into the PCB would probably be too broad, as you basically seem to have a non-reproducible error that is likely just a power instability related glitch.

Comment: any kind of question like this might gain traction in area 51, but would probably be shut down in favor of the actual manufacturer forums. Though I don't think my original question could even be understood there. Since it's not an EE fix, I think I should just delete my question, but I wanted to see what meta had to say first